# Проблема с exe форматом через pyinstaller (с pyqt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, ос, pyinstaller

Столкнулся с проблемой, которую мне не удалось пофиксить часами поисков на форуме. При конвертации моей в программы с помощью pyinstaller в exe формат, у меня не работает кнопка запустить игру. Выскакивает ошибка: this application failed to start because no qt platform plugin could be initialized reinstalling 
Вот пример кнопка, которая запускает игру.

```
import os

...

aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SOFTWARE\Bethesda Softworks\Skyrim Special Edition", 0, KEY_READ | 
KEY_WOW64_32KEY)
gPath, _ = QueryValueEx(aKey, "Installed Path")

skyrim = gPath + "Mod Organaizer/ModOrganizer.exe"

...

class Widget(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    ...

    button13 = QPushButton("Запустить", self)
    button13.move(450, 100)
    button13.resize(150, 50)
    button13.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial Black", 11, QtGui.QFont.Normal))

    ...

    button3.clicked.connect(self.skyrim)

...

def Skyrim(self):
    import os
    os.startfile(skyrim)
```

Comment: https://www.cyberforum.ru/qt/thread2570346.html

Comment: там про C++. Я не знаю, как это на питоне сделать.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin можете по русски объяснить. Я не могу понять, как это решить.

Comment: В директрии с Qt есть такая папочка platforms в plugins, которую надо положить рядом с вашим exe-шником. http://blog.harrix.org/article/1015

Comment: спасибо вам большое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поломался pyinstaller, просто надо переустановить.